# Checkbox Validation and MySQL data insertion

Tags: php, mysql, sql-server, html

I am trying to customize a  script for checkbox.

I have progressed to the following and successfully echoed to screen:

```
$q="Select id, subject From subjects";
     $r=mysqli_query ($d, $q);
     If (mysqli_num_rows($r)>0) {
        while ($row =mysqli_ferch_array($r, MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                Echo "<input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"$row[1]\" value=\"$row[0]\">$row[1]";
     }}
```

Now,

I am trying to insert the resultant data into a different table (for example student) as follows:

```
$q = 'INSERT INTO student (id) VALUES (?)';
$stmt = mysqli_prepare($d,$q);
mysqli_stmt_bind+param($stmt, 'i', $_POST[?);
mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
```

However, this is not working.

Where I am lost is trying to understand the variables:

`$row`, `$row[0]` `$row[1]` and `sql` `'subject'` `sql` `'id'`

What value will `$_POST` receive and how do I insert into a database using the above procedural type code that was used for a select statement.

If possible, would you provide an example?

Also, any explanation of the variables listed above and their uses would be helpful!

I have looked through the site, but still am a little confused.

Comment: This is all PHP/MySQL 101 so you may want to consider working through some tutorials which explain the concepts. codecademy.com is a good place to start.

Comment: You have a couple of syntax errors here `mysqli_stmt_bind+param($stmt, 'i', $_POST[?);`  The `+` should be `_` and `$_POST` is missing a closing bracket and identifier.

Comment: Yes, Jay.  Aplogies, they were typos. i know the correct syntax.  The ? is to indicate that I am not clear what to put here.  I hope this is a specific question.